# Assigning Function Keys to excel macros

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen the following example code suggested to assign function keys to excel macros but regardless of where I try to copy the code (module, workbook, worksheet), in it's entirety, the original assigned function key task is always performed rather than the attempted/assigned macro.  Does this code require some type of advance code to first disable the original assigned tasks of function keys?

```
Sub A_1()
  Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub B_1()
  Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\b1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub C_1()
  Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\c1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub D_1()
  Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\d1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub E_1()
  Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\e1.wav", 0)
End Sub


Sub auto_open()
  Application.OnKey "{F1}", "A_1"
  Application.OnKey "{F2}", "B_1"
  Application.OnKey "{F3}", "C_1"
  Application.OnKey "{F4}", "D_1"
  Application.OnKey "{F5}", "E_1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place this in the **workbook code area**:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "A_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F2}", "B_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", "C_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F4}", "D_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F5}", "E_1"
End Sub
```

Place your other subs in a **standard module**.

The OnKey assignments will occur when the workbook opens.  To restore normal function key behavior, run:

```
Sub reset()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}"
    Application.OnKey "{F2}"
    Application.OnKey "{F3}"
    Application.OnKey "{F4}"
    Application.OnKey "{F5}"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

yes but remember if the vba application exits abnormally (eg crashes) then the function key assignments remain and pressing a function key will reopen the application containing the reassignment, this can be disastrous if there is already a vba enabled application running (VBA NOT multithreaded). I know I've done it and had to pickup the pieces of the memory bashing